# Why can't I add an extra parameter to a function in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm making a todo app. I'm trying to add the event and the items.id to a button function (e.g. delete, edit, completed).

Normally in React this would work (I have made the todo app in plain React as well, there is no problem). With TypeScript I get an error saying, expected 1 argument, got 2. How do I specify the second argument in TypeScript?

```
function List({}: Props) {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useContext(TodoContext);

  const editButton = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  const deleteButton = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(todos);
  };
  const completedButton = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <ListWrapper>
      <ul className="list">
        {todos?.map((item) => {
          return (
            <>
              <li className="list__item">
                <div className="list-item">
                  <span className="list-item__todo">{item.name}</span>
                  <button
                    className="list-item__button list-item__button--edit"
                    onClick={(e) => editButton(e)}
                  >
                    Edit
                  </button>
                  <button
                    className="list-item__button list-item__button--delete"
                    onClick={(e) => deleteButton(e)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                  <button
                    className="list-item__button list-item__button--completed"
                    onClick={(e) => completedButton(e, item.id)}
                  >
                    Completed
                  </button>
                </div>
              </li>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </ListWrapper>
```

Comment: `const completedButton = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {` - that indeed only specifies one parameter. It doesn't declare the second at the _JavaScript_ level, even - have a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html.

Comment: Just put a second argument in the function signature and give it an appropriate default so you can handle both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function definition needs to have 2nd arg as well.

```
const completedButton = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>, id: string) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };
```